# How to handle events with MVC Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, event-handling, buttonclick

I'm implementing a mini program in C# using the MVC Architectural Pattern. The goal of this program is to update the value of a mouse click counter (which is in the Model), by clicking a button (which is in the View) through a Controller that must handle the Button Click Event.

The code I've written so far works (it compiles without errors), but if fails to handle the button click event because I can't figure out what kind of code I must put into the View and what into the Controller. The only solution I tried and found working is to give the View a reference to its Controller. In this way, the Event Handler is registered and implemented in the View and it invokes a method of the Controller (e.g. Controller.DoSomethingOnButtonClick()). But this solution breaks the MVC Pattern, because the View, as far as I understood, should NOT be aware of its Controller.

The Model (implements the Observer Pattern, it is the "observable"):

```
class Model : Subject
{
   private int counter = 0;

   public void IncreaseCounterByOne()
   {
      counter++;
      Notify(); // notify the observers
   }

   public int GetCounter()
   {
      return counter;
   }
}
```

The View (implements the Observer Pattern, it is the "observer"):

```
class View : IObserver
{
    private Model Model;
    private Form MyForm = new Form();
    private Label MyLabel = new Label();
    private Button MyButton = new Button();

    public View(Model model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
        this.Model.Attach(this);
    }

    public void CreateView()
    {
        // create and display the view (MyForm, MyLabel, MyButton)
    }

    public void Update(Subject subject)
    {
        UpdateLabel();
    }

    private void UpdateLabel()
    {
        MyLabel.Text = "Click Counter: " + Model.GetCounter();
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
class Controller
{
    private Model Model;
    private View View;

    public Controller(Model model, View view)
    {
        this.Model = model;
        this.View = view;

        this.View.CreateView();
    }

    private void UpdateCounter()
    {
        this.Model.IncreaseCounterByOne();
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the Controller catch the Button Click Event generated by MyButton and handle it in its Event Handler, which I assume to be something like:

```
public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateCounter();
}
```

How can I accomplish this without using a reference to the Controller? Is it possible?

PS. I already read a lot of similar questions, but not found the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a problem where trivial examples for patterns like MVC fall down: the UI often takes on both roles of V and C - it shows the data and offers a way to manipulate it. If your example were more involved (eg a web service is the controller)the concerns would be easier to see separated

The separation is still there logically, but you can't easily put the button in one class and the label that shows the counter in another as a method of separation, when you're essentially trying to combine it al in the same UI - but you shouldn't worry about this

Accept that your UI contains your view and also contains your controller so it's the UI class(es) job to unify all the things. Consider that your label is actually the view, not your class that happens to be called View. The concept appreciation you need to acquire is that you can have 3 different ways of changing the model (a timer, a button, a tcp socket that you send some data to) via the controller and 3 different ways of visualizing it (a label showing a number, a progress bar, a call to a website page that returns a string of 'A' as long as the current counter) and you've separated your concerns - the label/progbar/website are independent of the timer/button/website and they have no knowledge of each other, they don't interact, you don't need a reference to one passing into the other in order for everything to function. You can remove the button and the socket and the timer will carry on causing model manipulations that the label/progbar will carry on showing